# Add a value and sum it up using Notepad++

Tags: python, regex, notepad++

I am having a file wherein the data is similar as given below:

```
abc - $0.05
xyz - $0.01
rst - $0.09
etc - $0.4
```

What I want to do is, increment all the values by $0.02 so that the final sum will look like below:

```
abc - $0.07
xyz - $0.12
rst - $0.11
etc - $0.42
```

How can I achieve this using Notepad++

Thank you.

Comment: Honestly, I searched everywhere but couldn't find any solution to my problem.
Actually, I tried manually doing it and stopped after few lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)

Copy this code and save the file (for example `calculate.py`):

```
import re
def calculate(match):
    return '%s' % (str(float(match.group(1)) + 0.02))

editor.rereplace('(\d+\.\d+)', calculate)
```

- Open the file you want to change
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> calculate)
- Done

**Result for given example:**

```
abc - $0.07
xyz - $0.03
rst - $0.11
etc - $0.42
```

Note the difference from your expected second line (`xyz - $0.01` becomes `xyz - $0.03` and not `xyz - $0.12`)

Comment: That was quick and easy. Really appreciate your efforts and time to guide me like which a newbie like me can understand. Thank you so much.
Thanks for the correction too, my bad.