# Find text and increment an specific number of it with Notepad++ or any other method?

Tags: json, find, notepad++, auto-increment

first of all I have very little programming knowledge.

I have over 800 map.json files of RPG Maker that I moved on my project, to merge them into my project I had to rename the files from 1~800 to 2001~2800 with a software that only replaces the name of the files in batch.

This time I have to edit inside each json files to find for example this:

```
{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,267,
{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,1,
{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,367,
```

And increments the last number by 2000, something like....

```
{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,267,
```

to

```
{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,2267,
```

...

```
{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,1,
```

to

```
{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,2001,
```

Etc

EDIT:
A full line could be like this:

```
{"id":1,"name":"EV001","note":"","pages":[{"conditions":{"actorId":1,"actorValid":false,"itemId":1,"itemValid":false,"selfSwitchCh":"A","selfSwitchValid":false,"switch1Id":1,"switch1Valid":false,"switch2Id":1,"switch2Valid":false,"variableId":1,"variableValid":false,"variableValue":0},"directionFix":false,"image":{"tileId":0,"characterName":"!$fsm_Gate09","direction":2,"pattern":0,"characterIndex":0},"list":[{"code":250,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"name":"Earth4","volume":90,"pitch":100,"pan":0}]},{"code":205,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,{"list":[{"code":17},{"code":15,"parameters":[8],"indent":null},{"code":18},{"code":15,"parameters":[8],"indent":null},{"code":19},{"code":37},{"code":0}],"repeat":false,"skippable":false,"wait":true}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":17}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":15,"parameters":[8],"indent":null}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":18}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":15,"parameters":[8],"indent":null}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":19}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":37}]},{"code":230,"indent":0,"parameters":[12]},{"code":205,"indent":0,"parameters":[-1,{"list":[{"code":12},{"code":0}],"repeat":false,"skippable":true,"wait":true}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":12}]},{"code":250,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"name":"Move1","pan":0,"pitch":100,"volume":90}]},{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,267,15,25,0,0]},{"code":0,"indent":0,"parameters":[]}],"moveFrequency":3,"moveRoute":{"list":[{"code":0,"parameters":[]}],"repeat":true,"skippable":false,"wait":false},"moveSpeed":3,"moveType":0,"priorityType":1,"stepAnime":false,"through":false,"trigger":1,"walkAnime":false}],"x":17,"y":32},
```

Or could be this:

```
{"id":4,"name":"EV004","note":"","pages":[{"conditions":{"actorId":1,"actorValid":false,"itemId":1,"itemValid":false,"selfSwitchCh":"A","selfSwitchValid":false,"switch1Id":1,"switch1Valid":false,"switch2Id":1,"switch2Valid":false,"variableId":1,"variableValid":false,"variableValue":0},"directionFix":false,"image":{"tileId":0,"characterName":"!$fsm_Gate09","direction":2,"pattern":0,"characterIndex":0},"list":[{"code":250,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"name":"Earth4","volume":90,"pitch":100,"pan":0}]},{"code":205,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,{"list":[{"code":17},{"code":15,"parameters":[8],"indent":null},{"code":18},{"code":15,"parameters":[8],"indent":null},{"code":19},{"code":37},{"code":0}],"repeat":false,"skippable":false,"wait":true}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":17}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":15,"parameters":[8],"indent":null}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":18}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":15,"parameters":[8],"indent":null}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":19}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":37}]},{"code":230,"indent":0,"parameters":[12]},{"code":205,"indent":0,"parameters":[-1,{"list":[{"code":12},{"code":0}],"repeat":false,"skippable":true,"wait":true}]},{"code":505,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"code":12}]},{"code":250,"indent":0,"parameters":[{"name":"Move1","pan":0,"pitch":100,"volume":90}]},{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,6,11,20,0,0]},{"code":0,"indent":0,"parameters":[]}],"moveFrequency":3,"moveRoute":{"list":[{"code":0,"parameters":[]}],"repeat":true,"skippable":false,"wait":false},"moveSpeed":3,"moveType":0,"priorityType":1,"stepAnime":false,"through":false,"trigger":1,"walkAnime":false}],"x":19,"y":18},
```

You may notice that the lenght of the lines are very different size.
So I need to find the value:

{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,***x***,
And increment x by 2000.
Find the piece *{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,* is important since there are a lot more of numbers.

How I can do this with Notepad++? Or is there a easier alternative?

Will be awaiting for answers, I really need this to continue with the development of my project since it has over 600 warp points :(

---

To clarify, I did a research before posting this, the only things I found are these:
[Add a value and sum it up using Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197040/add-a-value-and-sum-it-up-using-notepad)

https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/19345/replacing-number-with-another-incrementing

[How do you do a Find and Insert in Notepad++ instead of a replace, while using regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541552/how-do-you-do-a-find-and-insert-in-notepad-instead-of-a-replace-while-using-r)

Tried the first one which seemed to be more close to provide me a solution, but I don't know how to adapt this script to my needs:

```
import re
def calculate(match):
    return '%s' % (str(float(match.group(1)) + 0.02))

editor.rereplace('(\d+\.\d+)', calculate)
```

Comment: There is no way in Notepad++ to do math in a find/replace operation. Asking for any other software is against the [help] guidelines. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading those [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: I'm asking for an alternative solution, not for an specific software.
I seen other articles which suggested use PythonScript but I couldn't make it work for what I wanted.

Comment: Your post title says *any other software*. That's a software recommendation request, which is off-topic. There is no way to do what you're asking in Notepad++, as I said before.

Comment: This would be relatively easy using something like Python or Java, but would be difficult/impossible using NPP.

Comment: Are those structures nested? `{"code":201,"indent":0,"parameters":[0,1,` is third value of parameters array from first object?

Comment: I edited my post, please see it again, it should be more clearer what I need. I found a possible solution but I don't know how to adapt it to my needs.